# Progress Circles Not Aligned With Label

Tags: html, css

The below code creates a progress circle with number in the middle.

I need each circle to have a label under it, but can't put it in either a span or div without disrupting the CSS circle; I ussed tables but I want it to look okay on mobile devices.

Any suggestions would be great.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

h1 {
  color: #63B8FF;
  text-align: center;
}

.progress-circle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}

.progress-circle:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: colorload 2s;
  animation: colorload 2s;
}

.progress-circle span {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #8b8b8b;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}

.progress-circle span:after {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #8b8b8b;
}

.progress-circle.progress-45:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ebebeb 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(90deg, #b4b5aa 50%, #ebebeb 50%, #ebebeb);
}


}
@-webkit-keyframes colorload {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-circle progress-45"><span>333</span></div>
<center>TAG A</center>
<div class="progress-circle progress-45"><span>4444</span></div>
<center>TAG b</center>
<div class="progress-circle progress-45"><span>555</span></div>
<center>TAG C</center>
```

I have tried to use tables but does not look great on mobile device.

Comment: The tag 'labels' ("tag A", "tag B"...) are centered in the page because that's the parent element of the (long-obsoleted, never-to-be-used) `<center>` element.

Comment: I'm assuming that this is what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/07z3xmyj/ ?

Comment: Yer. that seemed to work but animation has gone.

Answer (score 0):

Checked the code, seems like the label under it doesn't ruin the circle, even if you use `<div>` or `<span>`. here is something you could do:

Use a container to control the behavior of the circles and the labels:

```
  <div class="progressContainer">
    <div class="progress-circle progress-45"><span>333</span></div>
    <div>Tag A</div>
    <div class="progress-circle progress-45"><span>4444</span></div>
    <div>TAG b</div>
    <div class="progress-circle progress-45"><span>555</span></div>
    <div>TAG C</div>
  </div>
```

This way, you can control how the circle and the label behave in the webpage, you can give the class `progressContainer` a `text-align: center;` to make all of the code inside the class be centered (without using `<center>` which is bad practice), if you need to make them all align left, just change it from `center` to `left`.
I hope i understood your question correctly.

Comment: Tried this, but text seems to be at the right of the circles. @Phardin

https://imgur.com/4WR6y0f

Comment: My bad, @PaulJames , you need to use `<div>` instead of `<span>` for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for that @Phardin. But now one above the other opposed to being inline.