# Div not aligned

Tags: html, css

Need circles to be displayed horizontally

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq2w3.jpg

For css
See my other post
[Progress Circles Not Aligned With Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57936684/progress-circles-not-aligned-with-label/57937205#57937205)

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="progress-circle.css">

</head>

<body>

 <div class="progressContainer">

    <div class="progress-circle progress-45"><span>333</span></div>
    <div class="inline" >Tag A</div>    

    <div class="progress-circle progress-45"><span>444</span></div>
    <div class="inline" >Tag A</div>
    <div class="progress-circle progress-45"><span>555</span></div>
     <div class="inline" >Tag A</div>



  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: need better description... (including CSS)

Answer (score 1):

If you want this displayed horizontally try adding a container to the `progress-circle` and `inline` divs and apply the `display: inline-block` to the container like shown below:

Edit: Removed extra scope marker causing animation to fail.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

h1 {
  color: #63B8FF;
  text-align: center;
}


.circleCont {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.inline {
  text-align: center;
}

.progress-circle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  
}

.progress-circle:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: colorload 2s;
  animation: colorload 2s;
}

.progress-circle span {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #8b8b8b;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}

.progress-circle span:after {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #8b8b8b;
}

.progress-circle.progress-45:after {
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #b4b5aa 50%, #ebebeb 50%, #ebebeb),linear-gradient(90deg, #ebebeb 50%, transparent 50%, transparent);
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorload {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

     <div class="progressContainer">
         <div class="circleCont">
          <div class="progress-circle progress-45">
            <span>333</span>
          </div>
          <div class="inline">Tag A</div>
        </div>
        <div class="circleCont">
          <div class="progress-circle progress-45">
            <span>400</span>
          </div>
          <div class="inline">Tag A</div>
        </div>
        <div class="circleCont">
          <div class="progress-circle progress-45">
            <span>250</span>
          </div>
          <div class="inline">Tag A</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Akatsuki777 but the animation of the circle does not work

Comment: @PaulJames The animation does work fine, you've just got the gradient applied other way round, it should be `background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #b4b5aa 50%, #ebebeb 50%, #ebebeb),linear-gradient(90deg, #ebebeb 50%, transparent 50%, transparent);
}`